# What happens when the name of a C++20 concept is the same as the name of a class type

Tags: c++, c++20, concept

Does C++ define the behavior of the following code:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept C = true;

struct C {};

template <C T>
struct A {};

template <struct C T>
struct B {};

int main() {
    // when using MSVC

    C c; // error
    bool b = C<int>; // also error
                     // and can't use concept C anywhere other
                     // than the template parameter list

    constexpr struct C cc {};

    struct C c2; // ok

    A<int> a; // ok
    A<cc> a; // error

    B<cc> b; // ok

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone answer me:

1. Is this declaration correct ?

```cpp
template <struct C T>
struct B {};
```

I found this on cppreference:

> When used as a template argument, class T is a type template parameter named T, not an unnamed non-type parameter whose type T is introduced by elaborated type specifier

2. As mentioned above, can I define a concept and a class type with the same name? If the answer is yes, how do I specify that the name is a concept?

Comment: Both gcc and clang [reject it as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/nxezdPG7n).

Comment: I also think such a definition is not allowed, but on my visual studio this code compiles and outputs the correct result.@康桓瑋

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any template (other than a function template with overloads), you [cannot have anything else in the same scope with the same name](https://wg21.link/temp#pre-7).

So that means your declaration `template <class T> concept C` means that you can have no other entity named `::C`. This is defined as [ill-formed](https://wg21.link/basic.scope.scope#5.sentence-2), so the C++ standard says this code should not compile.

Your issue does appear if one is introduced via an inline namespace:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept C = true;

inline namespace x {
struct C {};
}
```

Now, `struct C` will refer to the struct `x::C`, and there is no way to unambiguously refer to the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So my code can be compiled, maybe there is a problem with MSVC ?

Comment: @ValueError Yes, MSVC is wrong to compile your code without an error